# Scroll element into view not working on iOS using appium

Tags: java, scroll, appium-ios

I am trying to scroll to view an element in `iOS` using `Appium desktop 1.13` and `java_client 7.0.0` with `iOS 13.1.3` but it returns an error:

> Error Domain = com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "Failed to find
>   scrollable visible parent with 2 visible children"

I already tried to use `element ID` and Xpath but both are not working. For Xpath it is not returning an error but it does not do the scrolling action.

```
String elementID = ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("element", elementID);
scrollObject.put("toVisible", "not an empty string");
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

The expected result is the screen will be scrolled to the element specified but what happens is when I used Xpath it is not scrolling without any error and when I used `elementID` it returns an error

Answer (score 0):

It seem that the scroll [command](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/) for iOS is

```
driver.executeScript("mobile: scroll", ImmutableMap.of("direction", "down"));
```

You should try this :

```
void Rolldown ():
   Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
   args.put("direction", "down");
   driver.executeScript("mobile: scroll", arg);

while (true):
   //Use wait explicit to detect if element exist. If not 
   // Rolldown()
   boolean exist = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath( "element")));
   if (!exist)
      Rolldown();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, I did these:

1. npm i appium-webdriveragent-driver
2. Downloaded https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent and then ran 
   ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh
3. Deleted webdriver agent app from my simulator and reran the test case

Comment: Thanks however I still encounter the issue above